# Dealing with Security component in a CakePHP 2 test case

Tags: security, unit-testing, cakephp, post, phpunit

I am trying to test a CakePHP action that deals with a signup form secured with the `Security` component. I have configured the component in a UsersController like this:

```
public $components = array(
  'Security' => array('unlockedFields' => array('password_again')),
);
```

I can execute the action in a browser, but whenever I run the test case it fails with the following message:

```
"The request has been black-holed"
```

I have tried to disable the validation inside the test case in several ways:

```
$this->Users->Security->enable = false;
$this->Users->Security->validatePost = false;
$this->Users->Components->disable('Security');
$this->Users->Security = null; // desperate measure :)

// still fails
$this->testAction('/signup', array('data' => array(...), 'return' => 'contents'));
```

But the test insists in using the `Security` validation of `POST` request. I am using CakePHP 2.0.3 and PHPUnit 3.6.3.

By the way, I am not using the `UsersController` directly, but a `TestUsersController` class that CakePHP baked for me (as a replacement for `generate` method, I think).

What's the right way of dealing with Security component in a test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to mock the `Users` controller and the `User` model and make expectations for the `Security::_validatePost()` method:

```
$this->Users = $this->generate(
  'Users',
  array(
    'components' => array(
      'Security' => array('_validatePost'),
    ),
    'models' => array('User' => true),
  )
);
$this->Users->Security->expects($this->any())
  ->method('_validatePost')
  ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```