# SecurityComponent black-holing my controller test case

Tags: security, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

Here's my **UsersController** test case:

```
<?php
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');

class TestUsersController extends UsersController {

    public $autoRender = false;

    public function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
        $this->redirectUrl = $url;
    }

    public function render($action = null, $layout = null, $file = null) {
        $this->renderedAction = $action;
    }

    public function _stop($status = 0) {
        $this->stopped = $status;
    }
}

class UsersControllerTestCase extends ControllerTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array('app.user');

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Users = new TestUsersController();
        $this->Users->constructClasses();
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Users);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testAdminSearchStudents() {
        $data = array('User' => array('search' => 'Ipsum'));
        $result = $this->testAction('/admin', array('return' => 'vars', 'method' => 'post', 'data' => $data));
        $this->assertCount(1, $result['users']);
    }

}
```

There's nothing special about my UsersController, but it uses the SecurityComponent (inherited from AppController).

And when I run the tests, i get the infamous:

> The request has been black-holed Test case:
>   UsersControllerTestCase(testAdminSearchStudents)

I think it's because i'm forging a POST request without the CSRF token and referal?

What should I do to make this work **without removing the Security component** from my Controller?

I'm not sure if this will help, but here's the important part of the stack trace:

```
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php : 230
SecurityComponent::startup
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php : 130
ObjectCollection::trigger
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php : 246
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php : 671
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php : 183
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php : 161
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php : 271
ControllerTestCase::_testAction
/var/www/source/cakephp/lib/Cake/TestSuite/ControllerTestCase.php : 189
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, i got the same problem, but i think the problem is not related to the post request, but the return type.
I get the same error on any get-request, when i change the return type from the default "result" to "vars" or other, post requests work without problems, even when the security component is active.
=/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem **mocking** the the `SecurityComponent::_validatePost` method:

```
$this->Users = $this->generate('Users', array(
    'components' => array(
        'Security' => array('_validatePost'),
    )
));
```

Inspired by [Dealing with Security component in a CakePHP 2 test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183396/dealing-with-security-component-in-a-cakephp-2-test-case?rq=1)